# Overwrite values in for-loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

How can i print values in same place when i echo the statement instead of printing the values in the same/next line (if using br tag). This is a sample for-loop

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
 echo $i;
}
```

The output will be:

> 0123456789

But I want my output to be the one as shown below as it should overwrite values in the same place.

> 9

I will display all the values slowly one by one using timer or sleep but my objective here is to overwrite the previous value or display it in the same place.

Comment: So, basically you want to print the last value?

Comment: You just want to echo the last value of the loop ?

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/bZjSP). If you simply want to show the last value only

Comment: If you want to make a timer - this is a wrong approach.

Comment: no i will make sure to display each value as a blink or in sleep but want all the values to be displayed in the same place

Comment: Please read about web basics.

Comment: You need to use AJAX or JS / jQuery, you cannot achieve the desired functionality like this. PHP will process it's code completely before outputting it to the browser.

Comment: The page isn't displayed until PHP finishes. The browser doesn't see all the changes as they're being made by the PHP script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you can't do it.
If you want to change the output in the browser itself, after you flushed the buffer, you have to use JS.

Think of it this way:
When you `echo`, you put some values in the buffer stream. When the buffer is flushed, you see the printed value in the browser.
You can manage the buffer, flush it, clean it, change it, but you can't change whats already out there.

I hope that helps some how.
Look at this link for more information about stream output:
[Output Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Comment: Thank you . Finally got the appropriate answer.

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help :)